# Scrapy Mongodb Connection

Tags: python, mongodb, scrapy, pymongo

I am scraping the data using scrapy.Now i want to store the data in mongo db for that i install `pymongo` but i am unable to connect to the databse
Here is my code for settings.py

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = ['tutorial.pipelines.TutorialPipeline',]
MONGODB_SERVER = "localhost"
MONGODB_PORT = 27017
MONGODB_DB = "test"
MONGODB_COLLECTION = "raw_prod"
```

Here is the code for pipelines.py

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import Connection

class TutorialPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        connection = pymongo.Connection(settings['MONGODB_SERVER'], settings['MONGODB_PORT'])
        db = connection[settings['MONGODB_DB']]
        self.collection = db[settings['MONGODB_COLLECTION']]
```

I am getting the following error

> cannot import name Connection

Where am i going wrong??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no such thing as 'Connection' in current pymongo (version 3) to connect you must use  [MongoClient](http://api.mongodb.org/python/3.0rc1/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#module-pymongo.mongo_client)
to connect to a db on local host and standard 27017 port

> from pymongo import MongoClient; c = MongoClient()